# Issue position scroll when Implement RecyclerView in NestedScrollView

Tags: android

I implement RecyclerView  with Header in NestedScrollView . But I get issue position of scroll. When the activity is paused then resume,the position is always auto scroll focus to RecyclerView.

[image]

My XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Header"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

So How To fix it ?

Comment: Hi, I have been stuck at the same issue for over a week now. Have you found a fix for it yet? :)

Comment: @edwinj http://stackoverflow.com/a/36645305/842607

Answer (score 4):

This should fix your problem:

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp">
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the header to stay in place, you should not use a scroll view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want the header to scroll off the top of the screen, then in your adapter you have to declare that you have 2 different view types, with the header being one and the rest of the cells in the RecyclerView the other.

You need to return different views then based on the position (you would return the header view for position 0, and the "normal" cell for any other position).

Comment: Then you need to declare that your adapter has 2 view types and assign one to the header. Wrapping a recyclerview in a scrollview is a bad idea as you'll get conflicting touch events.